# tumblr.js createPhotoPost using multiple images url

Tags: node.js, tumblr

I'm trying to user tumblr.js to create some photo post containing multiple images (from url). The method works fine when I use source (hence with a single url), but stop working when I try using data instead of source to send multiple photos at the same time.

My code is pretty basic for the moment but is still not working :

```
 client.createPhotoPost('myblog.tumblr.com', {data: ['http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg'] }, 
    function (err, data) {
      console.log("CREATE PHOTO POST", err, data)
    });
```

The error is API error: 401 Unauthorized which does not seem to be relevant.
Does anyone has already used this and has any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you make a demonstrable example? It sounds like you need an api key

Comment: I'm using tumblr.createClient to authenticate and it works like a charm with createTextPost and createPhotoPost using source instead of data